# url-loader with Webpack 5. Images are not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, urlloader

For a small front-end vanilla JS project, I am using Webpack 5. I will only have one HTML page with text and some small icons, so I would like to use url-loader for these icons.

I installed the necessary modules with this command:

```
npm install url-loader file-loader --save-dev
```

I configured the Webpack rule in the following way:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 8192, // in bytes
    name: '[name].[hash:7].[ext]',
    fallback: 'file-loader',
    outputPath: 'images',
    publicPath: 'images',
  },
},
```

Finally, I added this image to the index.html page:

```
<img src="/images/image1.png" alt="Image 1">
```

Here's the structure of my src folder:

```
src/
├── index.html
└── images/
    ├── image1.jpg
    ├── image2.png
    └── image3.gif
```

It seems that the url-loader is not working because I am not able to see the images on the browser, and the HTML related to these images does not seem to have been changed. I am able to use other rules such as SCSS and i18next, but I'm not sure what the issue is with the images. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`url-loader` and `file-loader` are deprecated in Webpack 5 and replaced by asset modules. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/.

I had this issue with fonts, but it can be applied to images too. In my case it was enough to replace

```
test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]' 
    }
  }
]
```

by

```
test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
type: 'asset/resource',
generator: {
  filename: './fonts/[name][ext]'
}
```

in webpack config.

Loaders that are used with `url-loader` or `file-loader` (example: `@svgr/webpack` in Create React App) might still need them. `new-url-loader` provides the functionality of both `url-loader` and `file-loader` using asset modules and URL assets. See for example https://github.com/marella/new-url-loader. **Disclaimer**: I have not yet tested this option myself.

Comment: Webpack 5 can handle these things per default without configuration. Here's an easy tutorial how to load an image with webpack 5: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easy-to-understand-guide-asset-module-webpack-5-prasenjit-sutradhar/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configuration you have provided, it seems that you have correctly set up the `url-loader` rule for images in your Webpack configuration file. However, there might be a problem with the paths that you are using to reference the images in your HTML file.

When you use the `publicPath` option in the `url-loader` configuration, it sets the URL path for the images that the loader is processing. In your case, you have set the `publicPath` option to `'images'`. This means that the URL path for your images should be `'/images/'`.

However, in your HTML file, you have set the src attribute of your  tag to `'/images/image1.png'`. This path is an absolute path, which means that it starts at the root directory of your website. Since your website is running on a local server, this path is not valid and might be the reason why your images are not displaying.

To fix this issue, you can change the src attribute of your `<img>` tag to a relative path that starts from the root of your website. In your case, you can use the following path: `'./images/image1.png'`.

Here's how your updated HTML code should look like:

```
<img src="./images/image1.png" alt="Image 1">
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried using ./images but the result seems the same. But, if I understand correctly,  my expectation was also to have the base64 data for the images that are lower then the size that I specified into the Webpack config.

Comment: One additional note also.. If I try to run the build command for production I don't see any images folder into the "dist" generated folder.